# -detailed-exitcode flag of Terraform not working inside GitHub Action

Tags: bash, powershell, terraform, github-actions

The `terraform plan` command has the option [-detailed-exitcode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#detailed-exitcode). With this option, the command should return the exitcode of 2 when it completes successfully and the diff is non-empty.

I'm having a problem whereby `terraform plan` exits with 0 despite the diff being non-empty and using `-detailed-exitcode`. This appears to happen only inside a GitHub workflow. When I run the command manually, it behaves as expected, exiting with 2. In the GitHub workflow, I rely on the [hashicorp/setup-terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform) action.

This is my GitHub workflow:

```
name: 'Terraform: Main'
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write
  pull-requests: write

env:
  working_directory: ./terraform

jobs:
  terraform_check_changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:

    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: "Terraform: Setup"
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version:  1.6.0

    - name: "Terraform: Init"
      id: init
      run: terraform init -backend-config use_azuread_auth=false -backend-config use_oidc=true
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{ env.working_directory }}
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_ID:  ${{ vars.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}

    - name: "Terraform: Plan"
      id: plan
      run: |
        set +e
        terraform plan -var "new_relic_api_key=${{ secrets.NEW_RELIC_API_KEY }}" -var-file environments/${{ inputs.environment}}.tfvars -no-color -detailed-exitcode
        exitcode=$?
        echo "Terraform exited with $exitcode"
        if [[ $exitcode -eq 2 ]]; then
          echo "planHasChanges=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          exit 0
        else
          exit $exitcode
        fi
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{ env.working_directory }}
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_ID:  ${{ vars.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
```

This is the output of the `plan` step

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/9efc414b-0934-467d-902b-9926937a2e8f/terraform-bin plan -var new_relic_api_key=*** -var-file environments/dev.tfvars -no-color -detailed-exitcode

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # newrelic_alert_policy.kamil_test_policy will be created
  + resource "newrelic_alert_policy" "kamil_test_policy" {
      + account_id          = (known after apply)
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + incident_preference = "PER_POLICY"
      + name                = "Kamil's Terraform test"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't
guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
Terraform exited with 0
```

I tried rewriting the `plan` step in Powershell but the exitcode was still zero.

```
    - name: "Terraform: Plan"
      id: plan
      run: |
        terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -var "new_relic_api_key=${{ secrets.NEW_RELIC_API_KEY }}" -var-file environments/${{ inputs.environment}}.tfvars -no-color
        $tfexitcode=$LASTEXITCODE
        Write-Output "Terraform exited with $tfexitcode"
        if ($tfexitcode -eq 2) {
          Write-Output "planHasChanges=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          exit 0
        } else {
          exit $tfexitcode
        }
      shell: pwsh
      working-directory: ${{ env.working_directory }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the current version of the `hashicorp/setup-terraform` GitHub action: see [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/152). It's apparently been fixed but the fix hasn't been released in over a year.

A workaround is to disable `terraform_wrapper`:

```
    - name: "Terraform: Setup"
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version:  1.6.0
        terraform_wrapper: false
```